# Multiple bibliographies, different entries with same authors and year

Tags: biblatex

I have two separate bibliographies, one for publications and one for working papers. They are in separate bib files.

The problem is that I have one working paper and one publication, both with same authors and in the same year. The way they are produced now prints next to author names (2020a) on the publications bibliography and (2020b) on the working papers bibliography. What I want is to have (2020) on publications bibliography (since it is the only entry with those authors and year in that refsection) and (2020) on working papers bibliography (again since it is the only entry with those authors and year in that refsection).

How do I do that?

On the preamble I have

```
\usepackage[style=apa, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{publications.bib}
\addbibresource{working.bib}
```

On the main part I have

```
\begin{refsection}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword={published},title={Publications}]
\end{refsection}
\begin{refsection}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword={working},title={Working papers}]
\end{refsection}
```

Comment: instead of loading both bib's in the refsection and then filter them, you should restrict the refsections to the respective bib, see the documentation.

Comment: I tried not loading anything in the preamble part and use the following but it still didn't fully work. It has (2020b) on one of the lists and (2020) on the other.

    \begin{refsection}[publications.bib]
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[keyword={published},title={Publications}]
    \end{refsection}
    \begin{refsection}[working.bib]
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[keyword={working},title={Working papers}]
    \end{refsection}

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you could provide a fully compilable example document (along with a few example `.bib` entries) that we can copy, paste and run on our machines. Such an MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) makes sure we are all talking about the same thing. Do you plan to cite any of the works in your document? (Since you are using `refsection`s your ability to cite the entries is already quite restricted.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @UlrikeFischer, it actually worked. I ended up including them both in the preamble, but restrict the refsection to each of them and it worked like a charm.

Also thank you for the comment @moewe!